# How to include part of a file?

Tags: php, file, text, include

I want to have one file from which PHP can source content text such as title, marquee and other small updates. I think I remember something like this in asp where you can point ASP to a line on a text file and it will pluck it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP file, create a class:

```
class Foo {

    public static function getMarquee() { 
        return 'marquee';
    }

    ...

}
```

Then you can just call whichever method you want from any file:

```
require_once 'foo.php';

echo Foo::getMarquee();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `file()` function reads in a file and explodes it by line breaks into an array (which it returns). Perhaps you could put each "entry" on a separate line and then simply grab it by doing something like `$filedata[$line]`.